# file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: sqlite, database

`DB Browser for SQLite`というツールを使ってデータベースファイルをエクスポートし、ターミナルでその中身を確認しようとしているのですが、「file is encrypted or is not a database」というエラーが返ってきます。調べたところsqlite3で作られたDBをsqlite2で開こうとするとこのエラーが出る事があるとのことで、とりあえず現在のsqliteのバージョンを確認してみたところ、バージョンは3.8.5でした。ということはsqlite2ではないですよね？なのに何故このエラーが出るのでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方に解決策を教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: SQLite2に限らず、データベースとして読み込めなかったというエラーです。SQLiteのバージョンが違う、データベースが暗号化されている、データが壊れている、SQLiteデータベースではない、などが典型的な原因ですが、いずれも心当たりないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。データベースが読み込めなかったというエラーなのですね。心当たりを探してみたのですが、原因が分からないです。。。データベースファイルの拡張子はsqlでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: それはひょっとしてSQLが書かれたテキストファイルではありませんか？だとすればSQLiteのデータベースファイルではありません。

Comment: なるほど、原因がわかりました。おっしゃる通りSQLが書かれたテキストファイルでした。テキストファイルからデータベースファイルへの変換などは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とりあえず、ここまでのやり取りを含めてまとめます。

> file is encrypted or is not a database

これはSQLite2に限らず、データベースとして読み込めなかったというエラーです。SQLiteのバージョンが違う、データベースが暗号化されている、データが壊れている、‌​SQLiteデータベースではない、などが典型的な原因です。

今回の場合 SQL が書かれたテキストファイルを開こうとしていたようですが、これは SQLite のデータベースではありません。

書かれているSQL、あるいはどのようにして生成されたSQLなのかによるのでなんとも言えませんが、

- （データだけでなく）テーブル定義などを含み
- SQLiteと互換性があるSQLで書かれている

のであれば、SQLiteで新規データベースを作り、そこにインポートすることができると思います。DB Browser for SQLite であれば、インポート時にデータベースを作成してくれるようです。

[データベースをSQL文形式でエクスポート/インポート - DB Browser for SQLiteの使い方](http://www.dbonline.jp/sqlite-db-browser/export/index1.html)

Comment: 返信が遅くなり大変申し訳ございません。エクスポートしたsqlファイルをDB Browser for SQLiteにインポートすると新たにファイルが作成されました。そしてDB Browser for SQLiteでテーブルとレコードを作成して値を入れて保存し、今回のインポートで新たに作成されたファイルをターミナルでsql文を打って確認してみると、レコードの値が出力されました！
インポート時に新たにデータベースを作成してくれるのですね。
大変助かりました。誠にありがとうございました。